# Decompression of request in self hosted WebApi service

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, compression

I have a self hosted WebApi. 
My client is sending a GZip compressed stream and i have an attribute which decompresses the stream in the OnActionExecuting override of an ActionFilterAttribute.

However my Details object in the controller is always null.

```
public class DatabaseAPIController : ApiController
{    
    [Decompression]
    public bool PostDetails([FromBody] IEnumerable<Detail> Details)
    {
         // The Details object is null.

         // This writes out the correct JSON which has been decompressed which proves my decompression method works.
         Console.WriteLine(Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);  

         // Do other work. 

         return true;
    }
}
```

This is the decompression attribute.

```
public class DecompressionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var content = actionContext.Request.Content;
        var bytes = content == null ? null : content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
        var decompressedContent = bytes == null ? new byte[0] : CompressionHelper.Decompress(bytes);
        actionContext.Request.Content.Headers.Clear();
        actionContext.Request.Content = new StringContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressedContent), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

If i remove the compression from the Client and the decompression attribute from the server then everything works fine.

I cant figure out why my decompressed JSON isnt populating the Details object in the PostDetails method.

**COMPLETE ANSWER**

```
public class DecompressionHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        var content = request.Content;
        var bytes = content == null ? null : content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
        var decompressedContent = bytes == null ? new byte[0] : CompressionHelper.Decompress(bytes);
        request.Content.Headers.Clear();
        request.Content = new StringContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressedContent), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        request.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", decompressedContent.Length.ToString());

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        return response;
    }
}
```

And i registered my handler in the constructor of my self hosted setup.

```
public partial class MainWebAPI : ServiceBase
{
    private HttpSelfHostServer _server;
    private readonly HttpSelfHostConfiguration _config;
    public const string ServiceAddress = "http://localhost:2345";

    public MainWebAPI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(ServiceAddress);
        _config.MessageHandlers.Add(new DecompressionHandler());
        _config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi",
            "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess is possible that parameters binding already happened during OnActionExecuting, so whatever you're doing there will not be seen by the model binder.

I think you should try using a [MessageHandler](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers):

```
public class CompressedMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Check for compressed message
        // Change the request
        // Call the inner handler.
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        return response;
    }
}
```

> Message handlers are good for cross-cutting concerns that operate at the level of HTTP messages (rather than controller actions). For example, a message handler might read or modify request headers.

which is more or less (the content) what you're trying to do here.

You will not need `[Decompression]` attribute anymore (which is good); you will need to use a custom http header from the client to indicate the handler that the content you're receiving is compressed; more or less the same that happen when you send a compressed response (which is managed by the system and not by you manually).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Ill update my question with my implementation.